# Proof verification for $f$ & $g$ surjective implies $fg$ surjective - Cohn - Classic Algebra Page 15

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> **Question:** Is this a valid proof?
>
> **Side question:** Am I less likely to get answers based on using notation $xfg=g(f(x))$?

---

I want to prove that if $f$ and $g$ are surjective, then $fg$ is surjective.

I have

$f:A\to B$

$g:B\to C$

And I know that:

1) $(\forall b \in B)( \exists a\in A) |( af=b)$,

2)$(\forall c\in C)(\exists b \in B) | (bf=C)$

---

If $f:A\to B$ and $g:B \to C$ are both surjective, then $fg$ is surjective.

Proof: $$(\forall c \in C)(\exists b_2 \in B)|a_2fg=c_2$$
$$(a_2 f)g = c_2$$
$$b_2g=c_2\blacksquare$$

Comment: Please don't close as duplicate. I know many proofs exist for this problem, but here my intention is to determine if *my* proof works(and get feedback on my logic once an answer is presented). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you clarify your notation, I dont see why you'll be less likely to get an answer. I am unfamiliar with this notation so forgive me if my response is not right on the money.

For your attempted proof, you did not quantify an $a_2$ before using it. You want:

Let $c\in C$. Since $g$ is surjective, there is a $b\in B$ with $bg=c$. Since $f$ is surjective, there is an $a\in A$ with $af=b$. Therefore

$$afg = bg = c$$

So for all $c\in C$ there is an $a\in A$ with $afg=c$.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I thought. Yeah the notation doesn't seem very common(although I already think it is better since it reads left to right), $g(f(x))=xfg$